# Ошибка при вставке строки в таблицу. Индекс 1 находится вне диапазона. Spring, JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, insert

Добрый день.
Изучаю Spring. Простейшая задача - вставить строку в таблицу.

```
CREATE TABLE [CoreJava].[Authors](
   [Author_Id] [nchar](4) NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[Fname] [nvarchar](25) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into  [CoreJava].[Authors] ([Author_Id] ,[Name] ,[Fname]) values ('PAUL', 'Paul', 'Starling' );
 (строк обработано: 1)
```

Делаем то же с помощью Spring:
Кодим bean

```
private static final String SQL_AUTHOR_INSERT = "insert into [CoreJava].[Authors] (Author_Id, Name, Fname) values (:Author_Id, :Name, :Fname )";

public void setJdbcTemplate (JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
   this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
@Override
public  void addAuthor(BookAuthor author) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("Author_Id", author.getAthorID().toUpperCase()); // Связывание параметров
    params.put("Name", author.getlName());
    params.put("Fname", author.getfName());
    jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_AUTHOR_INSERT, params); // Вставка
}
```

....

В основном модуле

```
    BookAuthorDaoJdbcImpl baBean = (BookAuthorDaoJdbcImpl) ctx.getBean("BookAurhorDao");
    BookAuthor ba = new BookAuthor();
    ba.setAthorID("PAUS");
    ba.setfName("Paul");
    ba.setlName("Starling");

    baBean.addAuthor(ba);
```

И получаю ошибку

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into [CoreJava].[Authors] (Author_Id, Name, Fname) values (:Author_Id, :Name, :Fname )]; Индекс 1 находится вне диапазона.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Индекс 1 находится вне диапазона.
```

Comment: P.S. Я понимаю, что проблема где-то в связывании параметров запроса.

Comment: Используется Spring 4.3.4 В нем я не нашел ни SimpleJdbcTemlpate ни NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Только просто JdbcTemplate.

Comment: Как не нашли? Вроде никто пока не запрещал [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html). Даже наоборот добавили [SimpleJdbcInsert](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html)

Comment: Да, точно. NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Надо было чуть внимательнее посмотреть. Из 4.3 похоже убрали SimpleJdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ. 
Собственно проблема оказалась в том, что JdbcTemplate не понимает "именованные параметры" в запросах, только старые добрые jdbc подстановки "?".
А я пытался использовать в запросе "именованные параметры".

Для именованных параметров нужно использовать .jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, который я сразу не заметил. На что указал Igor Kudryashov.

Меня запутало, то, что в релизе 4.3.4 нет SimpleJdbcTemplate, который умеет и так и эдак, и на который ссылается большинство учебников по Spring.